# Angular orderBy sub value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I have the following Object that I am ngRepeating over, that I want to sort by 'pricing.total'.

```
 "data":{  
  "12654fcd":{  
     "sequenceNumber":"12654fcd",
     "directionInd":"OneWay",
     "journey":[  ],
     "pricing":{
          "total":"1200.79"
     },
     "breakdown":{  },
     "validatingCarrier":"DL"
  },
  "1eb562ab":{  
     "sequenceNumber":"1eb562ab",
     "directionInd":"OneWay",
     "journey":[  ],
     "pricing":{
          "total":"1400.80"
     },
     "breakdown":{  },
     "validatingCarrier":"DL"
  },
}
```

And here is the Output:

```
 <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="itinerary in results.data.data |   orderBy:'pricing.total'">
```

My repeat is working fine, however I am trying to sort the output by pricing.total without any success.

How would I go about doing that? Is it even possible to achieve sort on a sub-value?

Cheers,

Comment: Could the issue be that the itineraries are not wrapped in an array? as in [{},{},{}] ? I can't change the output format right now, as it is coming from an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **orderBy**
>   - filter in module ng
>
> Orders a specified array by the expression predicate. It is ordered
>   alphabetically for strings and numerically for numbers. Note: if you
>   notice numbers are not being sorted as expected, make sure they are
>   actually being saved as numbers and not strings.

Order by works for arrays only. Yours is not array, its object.

Change your data structure to

```
"data":[  
  {  
     "sequenceNumber":"12654fcd",
     "directionInd":"OneWay",
     "journey":[  ],
     "pricing":{
          "total":"1200.79"
     },
     "breakdown":{  },
     "validatingCarrier":"DL"
  },
  {  
     "sequenceNumber":"1eb562ab",
     "directionInd":"OneWay",
     "journey":[  ],
     "pricing":{
          "total":"1400.80"
     },
     "breakdown":{  },
     "validatingCarrier":"DL"
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

$scope.by_pricing_total = function(it){return it.pricing.total}
then
orderBy:by_pricing_total

```js
angular.module('orderByExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.friends = [{
        name: 'John',
        phone: '555-1212',
        age: 10,
        data: {
          a: 57
        }
      }, {
        name: 'Mary',
        phone: '555-9876',
        age: 19,
        data: {
          a: 53
        }
      }, {
        name: 'Mike',
        phone: '555-4321',
        age: 21,
        data: {
          a: 51
        }
      }, {
        name: 'Adam',
        phone: '555-5678',
        age: 35,
        data: {
          a: 53
        }
      }, {
        name: 'Julie',
        phone: '555-8765',
        age: 29,
        data: {
          a: 52
        }
      }];

      $scope.getDataA = function(it) {
        console.log(it.data);
        return it.data.a;
      }
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<div ng-app="orderByExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <table class="friend">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:getDataA">
        <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
        <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That looked like it could work, but throws "Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token"

Comment: $scope.byPricingTotal = function(itinerary){
            console.log(itinerary.pricing.total);
            return itinerary.pricing.total;
        } 

and then orderBy:byPricingTotal without any console.logs showing, so I am guessing it is not being called.

Comment: i add code example, it should work,run and see the log, check why your code not going through

Comment: This will likely work, The issue seems to be that the objects are not wrapped in an Array. Thank you